# Positive quadrant dependence

Tags: copula, dependence

Gijbels et. al. [Positive quadrant dependence tests for copulas (25 page PDF)](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~omelka/Soubory/papers/pqd_2010.pdf)

What could potentially be application of this concept in economics and finance? From what I read from a couple of papers, they seem to be useful for modelling probabilities of consecutive portfolio losses in credit and insurance.

Can you guys think of anything else? Any use in hedging?

Also, how to compute positive orthant dependence? Any software available?

Comment: Could you explain the concept?

Comment: Pretty straightforward article. You can just read intro to get acquainted.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~omelka/Soubory/papers/pqd_2010.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiu_vqFhLvgAhWBUn0KHRQrAUoQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3Hsi6kiiZMUWe6EbPtT-8B

Comment: Please include ref in your question otherwise the question itself is unclear. Thanks